# msi install program as startup

Tags: windows-installer

is it possible to install a program as a start up program using MSI installer?

Comment: Do you mean, "How do I create an installer for deployment using visual studio"?

Comment: Ok you are a newbie so I won't downvote your question.  However you need to be more specific such as "How do  I create an MSI Install program that can install at the startup of a machine?"

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just install a shortcut to Start Up folder.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's possible. [Here's one way](http://makemsi-manual.dennisbareis.com/startup_folder_shortcut_to_provide_advertising.htm), apparently. And [here's](http://www.tarma.com/support/tin3/8000-kb/kb30005.htm) another.

Didn't try it myself though. If someone wants a program to appear in startup, they can just place a shortcut in the start up folder (of course, I'm aware that sometimes you have to offer it kindly to your users ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a silent install for an msi and script that via batch script or compiled application. Then schedule that script/program however you want. Without AD you might just insert the call to the script in the registry under RunOnce.

Or even better in an AD environment:
[How to use Windows Installer and Group Policy to deploy the VPModule.msi in an Active Directory domain](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/887405)

Comment: I think he's talking about installing a startup program using MSI, not installing an MSI at startup

Answer (score 0):

Sure, simply use the registry [Run keys](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314866) to start your application. e.g.

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

There's nothing special about Windows Installer in this case, you could easily use a non-MSI setup program to accomplish the same thing.